# Distributed behaviour of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 5 shards and 2 replicas and 3 nodes on same cluster.

Now the replicas are distributed in each node. i indexed bulk docs in that node.

```
 Now i _search in node 1. will it search in only 5 shards on node1 (or) will it 
 hit all 15 shards(including 10 replica shards) to retrieve doc i queried .
```

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will hit 5 shards but those shards can be primary or replicas.